# DNS filtering in PowerDNS recursive DNS

Tags: domain-name-system

I have installed PowerDNS as a recursive DNS server and would like to apply DNS filtering for users based on the source address and specific URLs. For example, User A with a 1.1.1.1 address, block [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com)

Is it possible to make a white/blocklist per user in PowerDNS, or I need a Firewall like **opnsense** to do this function? (~ 10K users)

Comment: Have you looked at Response Policy Zones? https://doc.powerdns.com/recursor/lua-config/rpz.html